# purrr: transform multiple specified list locations with the same function

Tags: r, purrr

Say I want to transform multiple locations in a list, specified by names or numeric positions, with the same function.

To do this with `purrr`, my current approach would be to write a new line for each location:

```
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

apple_info <- list(
  colour = 'green', 
  mass = '0.182',
  owner = list(
    name = 'Priti',
    height = '164.2',
    tesla_model_owned = '3'
  )
)

apple_info %>%
  modify_in(list('mass'), as.double) %>%
  modify_in(list('owner', 'height'), as.double)
```

But the code duplication is a little annoying, especially when you want to apply the same function at many locations, or when the transforming function is more complex than this toy example.

You *could* avoid it by looping over a list-of-lists-of-accessors with something like `for (loc in locs) apple_info <- modify_in(apple_info, loc, f)`, but this doesn't seem idiomatic or performant.

Is there a good way to do this in `purrr` without duplicating code? Is the functionality in a different tidyverse package?

(c.f. `dplyr` allows you to write one-liners that apply the same function to many data.frame columns using the verb + `across()` pattern and the now-superseded `*_at()` functions, which is analogous to the desired functionality.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you suggested is a good one. I don't think performance should be a big issue in this case, and to make it more idiomatic you could wrap it in a function to give a more '`across`' flavour:

```
modify_across <- function(.x, .where, .f, ...) {
  out <- .x
  for (i in .where) {
    out <- modify_in(out, .where = i, .f = .f, ...)
  }
  out
}

apple_info %>% 
  modify_across(list(list('mass'),
                     list('owner', 'height')), as.double)
#> $colour
#> [1] "green"
#> 
#> $mass
#> [1] 0.182
#> 
#> $owner
#> $owner$name
#> [1] "Priti"
#> 
#> $owner$height
#> [1] 164.2
#> 
#> $owner$tesla_model_owned
#> [1] "3"
```